# getting 'Duplicate resource' error after I created 2 transport requests in CDS

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, cds

I created two transport requests (TR) for same project while making changes in CDS views after that a duplicate resource error with error code 400 is showing and I'm unable to get any data in my UI5 table.

I transferred the changes which was locked in new TR to old TR but it is still giving the same error.

> HTTP request failed400,Bad Request,{"error":{"code":"/IWBEP/CM_MGW_RT/030","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Duplicate resource"},"innererror":{"application":...

Answer (score 3):

First of all: **Double check if there's actually no duplicate key** by reading the underlying SQL view (annoted in the CDS definition `@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName`) using the transaction `se16` (n/h).

If there are really no duplicates in the SQL view, the error can be caused by various bugs in the ABAP CDS framework. These bugs mostly do occur after you changed a CDS source/definition. Here a few of them:

- Open transaction `segw` and **refresh the entity structure** by right clicking "refresh all".

  [image: in edit mode].
- Afterwards click on the **red white beachball** to regenerate the MPC/DPC classes.

  [image]
- What the red white beachball actually does is kind of merging a the changed structure with the existing classes. Right click on the project and choose **"Generate runtime"** to really re-generate all of the runtime objects.

  [image]
- Sometimes there's a **clean up button** in the entities overview. Click it.
- In transaction `/iwfnd/gw_client` choose Metadata→**Cleanup Cache**→On both systems

  [image]
- Cleaning the cache works quite well for OData views that have been manually created from ABAP types in `segw` but Core Data Services might still be cached. In case none of the above helped:

  - logout and login again
  - restart the transaction
  - wait for an hour or two
- Try to **manually test the failing OData request** directly in `/iwfnd/gw_client`. You can activate logging in `/iwfnd/traces` to double check what the requests from your client actually look like.
- Check your OData client. Does it maybe internally cache the `$metadata`?
- Check that the transport request was successfully processed, using e.g. transaction `se10`. Transports/**Imports to another system might be blocked by long running SADL queries**. Kill them using `sm50` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks ,but it started working after i changed a search anotation of one of the field to false from true.

Comment: RIK thanks, can you describe your solution by writing a separate answer please? And adding precise information would be helpful too (instead of "changed a search anotation of one of the field").